# Why are the same two web pages appearing on the first page of Google's SERP?

Tags: google, url, google-search, ip-address, search-results

While searching in `google.co.in` for the keyword term "USA Boxing News", I found the same two web pages are showing on the first page of results. One result shows the IP address of the website, and the other one shows the URL.

Why is Google showing the same web pages twice on the first page of results? It could show different pages from the same website on the first page, but why is it showing the same two web pages? How is it showing the IP address as one result and real URL as another?

[image: same web pages in Google SERP]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although both the IP address and domain might lead to the same content at any given moment, the content for each was likely indexed on *different* dates. Note the differences in the snippet for the IP address, which starts with "5 days ago", versus the snippet for the domain.

It looks like much of the content there is dynamic and changes frequently, as other news-based sites do. Hence they're not the same web pages as of the date they're indexed on, and both are valid URL's - although the domain name resolves back to the IP address, Google can index IP addresses too.

Comment: And to point out the obvious - although a domain points to an IP, requesting the raw IP *can* return completely different content.

Comment: Usually these things fix themselves automatically (which seems to have happened here). If this is your website, you can fix it yourself by using the normal canonicalization methods: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066