# When I search on my domain name in a browser, the IP address is returned for my site hosted with GoDaddy and NGINX

Tags: dns, godaddy, ip-address, nginx, node-js

The IP address of my site is returned when I do domain name search in my browser.

*I am using:*

- GoDaddy Hosting
- Nginx
- Node.js

Obviously I would like the domain name and not the IP address, how can this issue be resolved?

Comment: I had asked a [question](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/51501/why-are-the-same-two-web-pages-appearing-on-the-first-page-of-googles-serp) that got an answer says [`'Google can index IP addresses too'`](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/51503/28169) but preferably you should do a 301 redirect to your domain or a canonical one. but seriously I'm not sure about this.

Comment: "when I type my domain name into a browser" - It sounds like you are suggesting that your domain name _redirects_ to your IP address? Or, are you searching on Google?

Comment: @w3d I think the OP meant the SERP displayed after typing their domain into the address/search bar (but not as a URL). I re-edited it to (hopefully) match their words more closely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this block to your NGINX config:

```
server {
       listen 80;
       server_name here.your.ip.address;
       rewrite ^ http://example.com$request_uri? permanent;
}
```